# Can I get my savings from my mom's bank now that I'm 18?

Tags: united-states, banking, bank-account

I turned 18 two weeks ago. My whole life I've had a savings account with my mom at Wells Fargo/Wachovia. However, I have a personal checking/savings account with my dad over at Bank of America which I put all my paychecks and such in to for regular spending and saving. I have no idea how much money is in the Wells Fargo account because my mom used to take money from it when I was a kid and swore she put it back. For all I know the account could be empty.

Is it possible for me to go to the bank and empty that account and then put it in my account at Bank of America so I have control over it? What kind of documentation do I need to get my money out? Any advice? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 10):

You need to find out *exactly*  how the two accounts are titled. If an account 
is an UGMA (Uniform Gifts to Minors Act) account that is in *your* name
with your mother/father as *custodian,* then you are entitled to all the money in the account when you become an adult. If the account is indeed a UGMA account, 
the *bank* is supposed to not let the custodian operate the account once the 
child becomes an adult, but this does not always happen.  There was a 
question earlier on money.SE (which I cannot find at this time) in which 
the 25-year-old person asking the question claimed that 
his father was still buying and selling shares in his UGMA brokerage 
account and the IRS was asking why the profits and losses from these
transactions were not being reported on the 25-year-old's tax return.
Money in an UGMA account is not supposed to be used for payment of
household expenses, food, etc. which is the parent's responsibility
during the minority,
but this can well be abused. As to whether money was taken out and
then restored (or possibly not restored, as you seem to suspect),
it is possible
to sue the custodian for improper handling of the UGMA account
and recover the funds, but whether one wants to sue a parent
over what might be a relatively small sum is another matter.
Consider whether most of
what is recovered might go to pay legal fees or other
costs of the recovery process, and will likely ruin
a family relationship.

If the accounts are titled as *joint* accounts, then either party can
empty the account without informing the other. But doing so would
need information about the account number etc. which you may not have.
For tax purposes, there is also the issue of whose Social Security 
Number is listed on the account, yours or your parent's.

See also [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/16361/5760) 
for a view of what happens from the other side.

Comment: Many states have an 18/21 statute, meaning the custodian *may* turn over the assets at age 18, but *must* turn them over at age 21. Check with your state to be sure